# Bug Menu Disabled Prestashop 1.7.5.2

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

just encounter a problem i can't fix.

The (automatic) menu module provided by prestashop disables itself twice or more in a day. Couldn't fix this until now.

It seems the module menu auto-disables when i make changes  in the menu (buttons, URL...) or on other modules.

I've contacted the developpers of my theme who never encounter this problem so i think it's not a problem with the theme.

Any ideas i can check to fix this ?

I'm on prestashop 1.7.5 and currently working in local (but same issue on my preproduction server)

Thx !

Comment: you should provide any relevant code

Comment: The fact is I didn't code anything in this module

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cache problem.
Delete the file "var/cache/prod/class_index.php" it will remake itself.
Also the delete the folder "var/cache/prod/ContainerXXXXX" after this, clear the cache trough the backoffice.

If this does not do the trick, you would have to share your server log's or your Prestashop's debug info (if it gives you anything)